# Elasticsearch searching in different results

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, eloquent

Im using Elasticsearch with laravel and Elasticquent https://github.com/elasticquent/Elasticquent over the Eloquent model.
Each user of my project can search in a different result of objects.
I have for example

```
$user_books->addToIndex();
Books::search($search);
```

And the problem is that everytime when someone go to the current step the elasticsearch is filled with his results.And at the end I have a combined result for each user with their books together.. which is a problem.
I need one user to search only into his results.
How can I achieve that? I think that I probably must delete the indexes after search because I dont need them anymore.

And then

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to delete your indexes,
instead you should index the books added by users by building a **custom index**
of their **user_id** like this :-

```
$data = [
        'body' => [
            'book' => '$book->name',
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,

        ],
        'index' => 'your application name',
        'type' => 'books',
        'id' => $book->id,
    ];
```

and then you can use custom queries to search for book belonging to that user only like this

```
$books = Book::searchByQuery(array('match' => array('user_id' => Auth::user()->id)));
```

Refer to Query based search and Indexing and Mapping section [here](https://github.com/elasticquent/Elasticquent)